# Pull named range from cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet used to generate monthly job cards. I need to set it up so it "knows" which month it's on, and on which day number a Monday falls. To this end I have set it up that each day number for every monday this year is listed. Each line on the daily task jobcard is serial numbered from 1 to 28,30, or 31 dependant on the month, so I have set up a formula to check the serial number for the daily task against the day number of each Monday. It works and I have checked this, but the only issue I have is that the formula `(=IF(COUNTIF(MARCH23MON,AJ6)>0,$AK$4,$AK$5))` requires me to change the `MARCH23MON` to match the range for each month up to 31 times every month.

Is there a way to do something like if the date = the date listed in cell a1, then use the value of cell b2 as the range (i.e. `MARCH23MON`).

See the screenshot here to see how I have begun to set this out. The date for each month is defined by the user in cell C3 when they generate the job cards for the upcoming month, this is then copied into cell AJ2 and formatted to match the dates in AP3:AP14.

[image: Screenshot of current setup]

I'd like to have the date defined in AJ2 to define the range the formula in AN6:AN36 uses from those listed in AO3:AO14, so that each month is checked against the relevant range of dates.

I had attempted to just use a vlookup then reference the output in this formula `=IF(COUNTIF(MARCH23MON,AJ6)>0,$AK$4,$AK$5)` as follows `=IF(COUNTIF($AL$2,AJ6)>0,$AK$4,$AK$5)` which obviously doesn't work. I tried it as `ADDRESS($AL$2)` but again no worky. Not sure if it is possible.

[image: vlookup]

Comment: Sounds like you may benefit from [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) or maybe [CHOOSE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc)

Comment: Thanks, choose didn't work the way I had initially tried setting this up, but using it to select each months mondays from the list as individual arrays works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Foxfire and Burns And Burns mentioned the CHOOSE function in a comment, and that has resolved this for me. Instead of using the list of range names I am now using CHOOSE
to select the dates of each month's Mondays from individual lists. I get the value of AL2 from a VLOOKUP function.

[image: solution]